# How to connect to a web-API enabled database via Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, webapi

On Windows 2007, I'm trying to use the following Access VBA subroutine I found on the internet to connect an Access (2016 64 bit) database to another web-API enabled Access (2016 64 bit) database to extract some data elements:

```
Sub DownloadFile0()

Dim Stm As ADODB.Stream
Dim Rec As New ADODB.Record
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Url As String, Str As String

Url = "http://www.elesteshary.com/sosdata.accdb/sdr/doll_per_sdr" ' URL, database, record, and field names

Conn.Provider = "ExOLEDB.DataSource"
Conn.Open Url
Rec.Open Url, Conn
Set Stm = Rec.Fields(adDefaultStream).Value
Str = Stm.ReadText
...

Conn.Close
Rec.Close
Stm.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
Set Rec = Nothing
Set Stm = Nothing

End Sub
```

When run, I received "Provider not found". Advise what provider may I use instead of "ExOLEDB" and how can I get it? When I bypass "Conn.Provider" statement I received "Data source name too long". Is this because the provider is missing?. Please correct the code if something is wrong. If all are set, will "Str" contain the value of "doll_per_sdr"? "sdr" is a one record table. What if I need to query a field from a specific record of a multi-record table. Finally, can this subroutine extract data from a database other than that of Access?

Note: It is not allowed to download the "sosdata.accdb".

Best regards.

Said El Noshokaty, PhD,
Professor of Information Systems

Comment: are you able to connect to the source *without* VBA  - through the `External Data` menu? ([example](https://support.microsoft.com/office/link-to-a-data-service-5ce2738f-bf36-4490-a015-d1745d102bb8)) That's always my first approach with a new data source since it's a little easier to flush out connection/authentication issues (it seems like I *always* have trouble with new data sources into Access -- they always take some messing around, and googling, but I always get 'em figured out eventually... good luck!) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. The code, you've found, requires a specific URL syntax and a web server knowing how to resolve it to be able to know:

- the database to open (sosdata.accdb)
- the table (sdr) to use in the database
- the index (doll_pr_sdr) of the record to retrieve from the table
- return that record

There is no such thing as an out-of-the-box *web-API enabled Access (2016 64 bit)* capable of this. Such an API would be built using a web server that publishes an API service that (internally) interacts with the Access database.

**Addendum:**

As you can download the file, you can use DAO for this.

1. Set References to include these:

[image]

2. Download and insert module `Internet.bas` from my project [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl)
3. Create a new module and copy-paste this code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function DownloadSdrValue() As Currency

    Const Url       As String = "http://www.elesteshary.com/sosdata.accdb"
    
    Dim Database    As DAO.Database
    Dim Records     As DAO.Recordset

    Dim FileName    As String
    Dim Value       As Currency
    
    FileName = DownloadCacheFile(Url)
    Set Database = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(FileName)
    
    Set Records = Database.OpenRecordset("Select * From sdr")
    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Records.MoveFirst
        Value = Records.Fields("doll_per_sdr").Value
    End If
    Records.Close
    Database.Close
    
    Debug.Print "Value:", Value
    
    DownloadSdrValue = Value
    
End Function
```

4. Compile and save the modules
5. Retrieve the value like this:

```vb
    DollarPerSdr = DownloadSdrValue
```

6. Result: 1.57

Comment: The URL is "http://www.elesteshary.com". In another subroutine, I was able to GET from the same URL a flat file using "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0".  Since this Microsoft protocol cannot deal with database table records and fields, therefore I searched the internet and I found the subroutine brought in my question.

Comment: The statement "using a web server that publishes an API service that (internally) interacts with the Access database" is unclear to me. "sosdata.accdb" is an access database which is uploaded to "elesteshary.com" and can be downloaded as well, nothing more.

Comment: "sdr" is a one record table in "sosdata.accdb". What if I want to query a field in specific record? Please advise.

Comment: OK, but why did you include that very confusing URL? All you wish now seems to be to download a file. No "API" is required for that - any web server can host a file for download. So, please update your question to include the actual information.

Comment: The question is updated as requested.

Comment: Thank you Gustav for the solution you have provided. Though, it actually downloads the file "sosdata.accdb" in a temporary place on my computer. Two precautions come about in this solution. First,  it assumes the file as an access database which is not always the case. Second, the client, where the file is located on his web server, won't allow seeing all the data elements by downloading. I'm wondering whether the subroutine I put in my question can help (source:  http://www.academictutorials.com/ado/ado-record-object.asp)

Comment: That link is about a _text file_ in an _Exchange store_, whatever that is, but it is very different from an Access database hosted in a web server. Also, you can't pull records and fields from just "a file of some format". If the client doesn't want the full database for download, ask him/here to export the table in question to a new database, and publish that. Then download that file and read the data using my code.

Comment: Or, may be, through a REST-API routine at the client side who could receive HTTP requests and respond back with the authorized data items from any type of database. Is this correct? If correct, please advise where can I find a tutorial on how to construct such routine. And, what VBA routine will look like from the requesting side?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is correct, but such broad questions are OT here at SO, which is about code helping. There are, however, bunches of guides/tutorial to find by a bing/google search. Alos, Visual Studio even offers, for example, a template for an _ASP.NET Core Web API_.

Comment: Thank you Gustav for being helpful.